# Does a multiple child selector exist?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I need to zero out a margin when any type of list (ordered, unordered, or definition) is contained within another list.  So I've written this SCSS:

```
#main ol, #main dl, #main ul { 
  & ol, & dl, & ul { margin-bottom: 0; }
}
```

Which results in this CSS:

```
#main ol ol, #main ol dl, #main ol ul, 
#main dl ol, #main dl dl, #main dl ul, 
#main ul ol, #main ul dl, #main ul ul { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

This **functions** as I expect it, but writing out each child list type (`& ol, & dl, & ul`) seems repetative.  I expect that I'm missing some sassy optimization here.  Is there a way to specify multiple children in a more terse manner than I've done here?

Comment: The `&` is only necessary when you don't want the whitespace: `ul { &.foo {} }` becomes `ul.foo {}` while `ul { .foo {} }` becomes `ul .foo {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the `&` in this case.  The following will work:

```
#main ol, #main dl, #main ul { 
  ol, dl, ul { 
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```